# In moving from 16.04 to 18.04, how can this custom shortcut be made to work?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, shortcut-keys, xorg

On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I have a custom shortcut set that features the following command:

```
bash -c "xvkbd -text $(date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H%MZ" --utc) 2>/dev/null"
```

On 16.04, this outputs "typed" text like "2018-11-21T1702Z" when I press a key combination like `Shift`+`Ctrl`+`d` which is really useful for my work and I use it about once per minute, to maybe name a file or enter some timestamp in a file, that sort of thing. The point is that I use it so much that I can't easily live without it.

Now when I try to set up the same thing on 18.04, when I press the relevant shortcut keys, while I expect to get output like "2018-1-21T1703Z", I get output that is just "--TZ" or no output at all. Note that the command run in the terminal works fine; it is when it is set as a shortcut that it doesn't work.

So, it is certainly trying, but getting screwed up in some way. I have confirmed via `$XDG_SESSION_TYPE` that I am running the X server and I have also confirmed that `xvkbd` is installed, so I am confused.

Would anyone have any ideas about what is going wrong?

---

EDIT: One suggestion mentions quotation marks. I don't think this is the cause. The quotation marks are a concern in something like Python, not Bash. I suspect the suggestion has been run only in the terminal, not as a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

It works, replace the wrong quotes:

```
bash -c 'xvkbd -text $(date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H%MZ" --utc)'

2018-11-21T1930Z
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your suggestion. I've tried using the exact code you suggested, but it is not working. Are you sure you have tried using it *as a keyboard shortcut*? So, specifically this command would be added as a keyboard shortcut that is activated by, say, `Shift`+`Ctrl`+`d`. When I do this I get only the `--TZ` output. Also, I don't see a reason why the quotes I used should be considered "wrong".

Comment: Look close on question, there are nested double quotes " . No, I haven't try it as shortcut

Comment: Yes, I can see the quotation marks you have used. I am not aware of any reason why my version is wrong. Are you?

But I think this is not the important issue. The issue is getting the command to work *specifically* as a keyboard shortcut on Ubuntu 18.04. Would you be willing to try that?